# chrome developer tools does not show tooltips on variables any more

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When I put a breakpoint on an element and I rollover it, chrome developer tool does not show aits value anymore.

It used to work before. I disabled all plugins, I started in private mode anb did not help.

I use Version 33.0.1750.117 m